# Google Script: Generate HTML Chart Using UrlFetchApp Trigger

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-visualization

First time posting on here and I'm learning as I go with both Javascript and Google's scripting capabilities so apologies if I'm not being clear enough or if I've missed another thread with an answer similar to mine.

Just to give a little background on what I'm trying to do in case I've missed a simpler solution I'm working on a Google script building a summary report to a Google doc from a Google form submission for a client and he'd like a graph including with a summary of a bunch of linear scale choices, so I need to find a way to generate the chart, output to a file (or get the blob) and then insert into the summary doc. At first I visited the Charts API (from inside the google script) which seems to be more suited to the method I'm aiming for, but the visualisation seems fairly limited so I've since moved on to investigating the html-based google.visualisation version of the chart which is yielding better results.

To date I've managed to create a google web app which spits out a decent looking chart for my purposes (using flat data for now while I'm testing stuff out) and output to a google drive spot for dropping into the google doc at a later date (code below) which works fine when I open the script app in my browser. The bit where I'm running into issues is that this being part of a broader workflow I'm trying to figure out how to trigger the chart generation either by running as a function in my broader script or by using the UrlFetchApp function to call the existing web app to build the chart using a get request, which the script doesn't seem to like... best I can figure out is that it's spitting out the html from the web app but not triggering the functions in the app, and I can't figure out if this is an intentional block on Google's part or if I'm calling the script incorrectly to trigger the chart generation.

Apologies if I've not explained this very well, and I'm happy following up if I've missed any bits, but I'd appreciate any help with this if anyone's overcome a similar issue.

Thanks,
Niall

Code:
Script.js

```js
function doGet(e) {
    
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html');
    
    return template.evaluate('Web App Window Title').setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    
}

function doSomething(base64Blob) {

    strDataURI = base64Blob.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
    
    var str = Utilities.base64Decode(strDataURI);
    var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(str).setContentType('image/png').setName("graph.png");
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(fileBlob);
    
}
```

html.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Load the AJAX API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      runDrawChart();

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      
      function runDrawChart() {
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      }
      
      // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

      // Create the data table.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'EXCERCISE');
      data.addColumn('number', 'SCORE');
      data.addRows([["1. Call", 5],
["2.1. Character A-1", 3],
["2.1. Character A-2", 1.2],
["2.2. Character B", 4.3],
["3. Chemistry", 6.7],
["4.1. Competencies-1", 9.3],
["4.2. Competencies-2", 8.9],
["4.3. Competencies-3", 4.5],
["4.4. Competencies-4", 2],
["4.5. Competencies-5", 1.4],
["4.6. Competencies-6", 8.7],
["4.7. Competencies-7", 5],
["4.8. Competencies-8", 7.4],
["4.9. Competencies-9", 9],
["4.10. Competencies-10", 3.3]]);

      // Set chart options
      var options = {
        width: 1200,
        height: 700,
        bar: {groupWidth: "22%"},
        fontSize: 22,
        legend: { position: "none" },
        chartArea:{left:600,right:20,top:0,bottom:50,width:'100%',height:'100%'}
      };
      
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
        
        google.script.run.doSomething(chart.getImageURI());
      });

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body> //Div that will hold the pie chart <div id="chart_div" style="width:400; height:300"
        ></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the code to another function which I attempted to call the one above to get the chart image:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  
  try {
        var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/[ID]]/exec';
        
        var options = {
            "method": "GET",
            "followRedirects": true,
            "muteHttpExceptions": true
        };
        
        var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    }
    catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e);
    }
    
    Logger.log(result);

}
```

Comment: will you please expand on _The bit where I'm running into issues_? what happens when you try either method?

Comment: Try working with some of the tutorials in google visualization documentation.

Comment: Yep, happy expanding - so based on the code above I was expecting the drive app to generate the chart image every time I called the app using the UrlFetchApp command from my base script (based on the doSomething function) but this isn't happening - it does seem to be returning the html page that I've pasted above but it doesn't seem to be filling in the div with the image blob nor calling the doSomething function.

Comment: I'll check out the google visualisation tutorials and happy plugging away at this but I just thought it worth checking in on this in case there's any reason I won't be able to achieve this in the way I'm trying to (I'm still getting the hang of Google scripting and I've not used the html side of things very often at all so I'm trying to figure out how everything interconnects)

Comment: You are mentioning UrlFetchApp but I cannot see it anywhere in your code. Could you clarify that, and provide the code where you're calling it?

Comment: Yep, no problem - I've just adjusted the question at the top to include the snippet from another script I'm using to try pulling the chart (and I'm happy to expand if needed).

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to build the graph client-side? Why not building it directly on the `doGet` function? Is that page ever supposed to be visited by a browser?

Comment: No, the browser aspect isn't needed - I'm probably tying myself in knots unnecessarily but with my limited knowledge of how the process works it seemed necessary as this chart generation is part of a broader workflow (which itself has a doGet form submission trigger) and (from what I understand) the html service can only be delivered from the doGet() function... with this to my mind the only way of invoking was by putting into an isolated web app and calling it from my other workflow. If it can all be done in the same place though or I can avoid the html aspect completely that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with in the end in case it'll be of use to anyone... it's a bit of a hack but is working as per the terms of my original question.

In the end I couldn't find a scripted way of calling the html chart page as it would when I opened in a browser so I found a workaround where I call the web app building the chart using Google's pagespeedonline service which calls the web app and builds the chart image for me (not part of it's intended use but it does the trick)... again, sure there's a more elegant way of achieving this but this works for now.

I've tried commenting throughout the scripts to describe the workings of the script but apologies if anything's unclear:

**First Google Script code with the source data that I want to turn into a chart:**

*Code.gs*

```js
//can be run as part of a larger workflow in a script if you need to pass the chart data from elsewhere
function doGet(e) {
    
    //assign a unique identifier to know what the chart will be called when picking up later on
    var thisUuid = Utilities.getUuid();
    
    //data stored as part of the example here, but you can reconfigure to your liking as long as you
    //alter the chart generation java accordingly in the html page: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples#mouseover-tooltip-example
    var jsonData = [[" Tarantella (1989)", 7.2],
                ["Larceny (1996)", 7.8],
                ["Doodlebug (1997)", 7.1],
                ["Following (1998)", 7.5],
                ["Memento (2000)", 8.4],
                ["Insomnia (2002)", 7.2],
                ["Batman Begins (2005)", 8.2],
                ["The Prestige (2006)", 8.5],
                ["The Dark Knight (2008)", 9.0],
                ["Inception (2010)", 8.8],
                ["The Dark Knight Rises (2012)", 8.4],
                ["Interstellar (2014)", 8.6],
                ["Quay (2015)", 6.8],
                ["Dunkirk (2017)", 7.9],
                ["Tenet (2020)", 0]];
    
    //specify a folder id where you'd like your file to end up (can be avoided but might make tracking the output file a little more difficult)
    var outputFolderId = //[put drive folder id here]
    
    //uri encode the parameters for passing as part of url in pagespeedonline url fetch
    var timestampEncoded = encodeURIComponent(thisUuid);
    var jsonDataEncoded = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    var folderIdEncoded = encodeURIComponent(outputFolderId);
    
    //declare the id of the google app with the chart building function in it
    var chartBuildAppId = //[insert app id here];
    
    //builds the url you'll be calling including the parameters it needs to build the chart
    var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/' + chartBuildAppId + '/exec?thisUuid=' + thisUuid + '&jsonData=' + jsonDataEncoded + '&folderId=' + folderIdEncoded;
    
    //url encode so it can be included as part of the pagespeedonline url
    var urlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(url));
    
    //get your API key here: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started
    var pageSpeedOnlineApiKey = //[insert pagespeedonline API Key here];
    
    //call the pagespeedonline link to trigger the chart generation with the parameters fron above
    try {
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&key=' + pageSpeedOnlineApiKey;
        
        var options = {
            'method': 'get',
            "contentType": "application/json",
            'muteHttpExceptions': false
        };
        
        var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
        
        //providing the fetch is successful we can grab the file by name using uuid above (used as it will be unique) and retrieve the file ID for editing/using as needing
        outputImageId = DriveApp.getFolderById(outputFolderId).getFilesByName(thisUuid + '.png').next().getId();
    }
    catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e);
    }
    
    //all being well we now have the id of the outputted chart image and can do what we like with it as part of a broader workflow
    Logger.log(outputImageId);
}
```

**Second Google Script which receives the get request and builds the chart**

*Code.gs*

```js
function doGet(e) {

//take the parameters from the first script and parse in the case of the json
var passedUuid = e.parameter.thisUuid;
var passedJson = e.parameter.jsonData.toString();
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(passedJson);
var passedFolderId = e.parameter.folderId;

//declare the html chart builder and pass the parameters over
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html')
template.jsonChartData = passedJson;
template.fileNameUuid = passedUuid;
template.folderId = passedFolderId;

//call the chart builder
return template.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

}

//gets the chart data from the html page and turns into a file for using elsewhere
function saveChartAsImage(base64Blob, fileNameUuid, folderId) {

var graphFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

//take the graph in its raw image format and transform for setting the file content
strDataURI = base64Blob.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
var str = Utilities.base64Decode(strDataURI);

//declare the file content and the file name
var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(str).setContentType('image/png').setName(fileNameUuid + ".png");

//output to a file
graphFolder.createFile(fileBlob);

}
```

*html.html*

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Load the AJAX API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    
    //declare the variables needed from the script.gs page
      var jsonChartData = <?= jsonChartData ?>;
      var fileNameUuid = <?= fileNameUuid ?>;
      var folderId = <?= folderId ?>;
      
      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      runDrawChart();

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      function runDrawChart() {
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      }
      
      // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

      // Create the data table.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'EXCERCISE');
      data.addColumn('number', 'SCORE');
      data.addRows(JSON.parse(jsonChartData));

      // Set chart options
      var options = {
        width: 800,
        height: 700,
        bar: {groupWidth: "22%"},
        fontSize: 22,
        legend: { position: "none" },
        chartArea:{left:300,right:20,top:0,bottom:50,width:'100%',height:'100%'}
      };
      
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        
        var chartIm = chart.getImageURI();
        chartIm.ready = true;
        generateChartImage();
        
        function generateChartImage() {
        google.script.run.saveChartAsImage(chartIm, fileNameUuid, folderId);
        }
        
      });

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body> //Div that will hold the pie chart <div id="chart_div" style="width:400; height:300"
        ></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
function drawGasTestChart(dt){
      if(dt){
        var hA=dt[0];
        dt.splice(0,1);
        var dA=dt.slice();
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        for(var i=0;i<hA.length;i++){
          if(i===0){
            data.addColumn('string',hA[i]);
          }else{
            data.addColumn('number',hA[i]);
          }
        }
        data.addRows(dA);
        var options={
        title:'Gas Test Results',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontName: 'Roman',
        width:640,
        height:400,
        hAxis:{slantedText:true,slantedTextAngle:90},
        legend:{position:'bottom'},
        chartArea:{left:75,top:75,width:'60%',height:'50%'},
        series:{0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}, 2: {targetAxisIndex: 1}},
        vAxes: {0: {title: '%LEL'},1: {title: 'PPM'}}
        };
        var chart=new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('GasTest'));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'ready',function(){
        gdatObj['imagURI']=chart.getImageURI();
        gdatObj.ready=true;
        saveGasTestChartImage();
    });
        chart.draw(data,options);
      }
    }

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAllCharts);
    console.log('charts.html code');
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for this - I'm sure it's down to my understanding of the code snippet posted but I still couldn't get it to work for my purposes of calling from a function/urlfetchapp. For the time being I think I've found a (admittedly inelegant and clunky) workaround where if I invoke the script using the googleapis.com/pagespeedonline service it will successfully spit out the graph file at the other side, so I'll use this as a workaround for now and will try making a more conventional fix work in the long run.

Comment: I don’t call it from UrlFetchApp. I have it embedded in a web app and they work perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, and can this be called from within a script to build the chart using your method? I'm probably still misunderstanding but my issue wasn't with building the chart itself (that worked fine when opening up my web app in my brower) but rather building the chart as part of my larger workflow.

Comment: I don't what you mean by `building the chart as part of my larger workflow`.  This method is for pure clientside javascript.  Although, the image that it produces can be use anywhere.

Comment: I'm trying to generate the chart on the fly as part of a script which is turning a google form submission into a summary report which will include the charts I'm working on generating. My use of the client side code is incidental as it was the only way I could figure out of generating the chart  in the first place but if there's another method of using the google visualization without relying on the client side html that would be great... I'm probably making way more difficult than it has to be but it was the only way I could see to implement the visualisation stuff at the time.

Comment: I see.  I have found it quite difficult to build charts using the embedded charts in Google Sheets.  Fortunately, most of my work with clients involves web apps so it's appropriate to use the client side approach and then I just save the image that you obtain with `google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'ready',function(){
        gdatObj['imagURI']=chart.getImageURI();
        gdatObj.ready=true;
        saveGasTestChartImage();` and I then use that image for use in client customer reports.

Comment: No problem - and yep, the scripted method of building the charts seems a little limited compared to the visualisation method which is how I fell down this rabbit hole. As mentioned a little above the googleapis.com/pagespeedonline method using their API seems to be doing a good job of calling the web app which inadvertently spits out my charts for me, so for want of a more elegant solution I may just stick with this for now as I can call this from my main workflow... not the cleanest of solutions but it seems to be doing the trick so I'll take that as a win for now.

Comment: May I ask you if you could supply a proper link to your approach? So I and others could get to it more easily.  Thanks

Comment: To the chart app do you mean? Or the workaround in building the chart using the pagespeedonline API?

Comment: Yep, sure - I'll drop into an answer below a little later on with the script I used to call the chart generation web app.